# Does this sentence sound ok in English?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, american-english, british-english

Does this sentence sound ok in English?

> The political decisions will be reflected on stock prices in a short period of time.

If it doesn't, what verb or structure should I use?

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is mostly fine BTW except for the use of on instead of in.

> The political decisions will be reflected **in** stock prices in a
>   short period of time.

The sentence structure depends on your audience. Please state your concern with the sentence structure so the community can be of further help.